# Use ChainMapper with TableMapReduceUtil

Tags: hadoop, hbase

Is it possible to chain multiple mappers when the first mapper in the chain reads from a HBase table? That is, to use ChainMapper with TableMapReduceUtil?

I'm trying to perform some transformations on each record retrieved from the HBase, but I'm not able to make it work.

Here's a code snipped where are try to use the two:

```
    Job job = new Job(hBaseConfig, "Retrieving data from HBase");
    job.setJarByClass(DataRetrievalDriver.class);

    Scan scan = scanCreator.getScan();

    TableMapReduceUtil.initTableMapperJob(
            table,
            scan,
            DataRetrievalMapper.class,
            Text.class,
            ElementWritable.class,
            job,
            true,
            SaltTableInputFormat.class
    );

    ChainMapper.addMapper(job, TransformMapper.class, Text.class, ElementWritable.class, Text.class, ElementWritable.class, new Configuration());

    SequenceFileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path("out"));

    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(1);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
```